# OpenXML Open SpreadsheetDocument from HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, excel, openxml-sdk

I'm trying to create an excel file from an HTML file using MVC5.  My HTML is a table with some additional markup in the HTML tag

```
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>Test</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 2%;">
        <col style="width: 16%;">
        <col style="width: 32%;">
        <col style="width: 16%;">
        <col style="width: 16%;">
        <col style="width: 16%;">
        <col style="width: 2%;">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
        ...
    </thead>
    <tbody id="worksheetBody">
        ...        
    <tfoot>
        ...
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

I had this working using the interop library but that's obviously not a very sound solution as it's a pain for deployment.  This was the code I had working.

```
        var wb = app.Workbooks.Open(Filename: @"C:\test.html");
        wb.SaveAs(Filename: @"C:\tmp.xlsx", FileFormat: XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLWorkbook);
        wb.Close();
```

The reasoning why you see me doing this was that in the following Fiddle, you get an annoying pop up about file extension being different than the format.

http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/wVejP/

I'm trying to replicate the above code using OpenXML but when calling the SpreadsheetDocument.Open method it is saying my file is corrupt, which is the same file I was using in the interop code.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this without using Interop?

Comment: you are calling `Open()` on an .html file?

Comment: Yes in both OpenXML and in the Interop code.  Interop code works, OpenXML throws error saying "File contains corrupt data"

Comment: yes because (as my answer indicates) the html is not a valid OpenXml format for an Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

Because Html is not a valid format, it's expecting the OpenXml structure for Excel files.

OpenXml is used to read or write Excel files, there is no analogous code to what you are doing.  Your code is using the OLE automation to convert a html file.  Here is a link that outlines how:

http://blogs.office.com/2014/06/25/open-xml-sdk-goes-open-source/